# Can I add a variable or a function in a mdDialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to add a variable or a function to my mdDialog. Im not to sure on how to create a custom mdDialog, Im new to angularjs.

This is my mdDialog:

```
vm.dialog_up = function() {
     vm.dis = true;
      alert = $mdDialog.alert()
        .title('Attention, ')
        .content('Do you want to edit your Information?')
        .ok('Close');


      $mdDialog
          .show( alert )
          .finally(function() {
            alert = undefined;
          });
    }
```

I want to maybe add a function to the .ok button.

Comment: I got it working. .ok('title', var a = true). I have not tried it with functions yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a very liberal language and it allows you to add properties and methods to objects. For example:

```
 var modal = {};

 modal.x = 5;//this assigns the value of `5` to the newly attached property `x`

 modal.testMethod = function() {
     //Do something here
 }
```

***PS:*** 
Though personally, I think that modifying framework objects can cause side effects.

Comment: So... you mean i cant add any functions to the framework object that im using?

Comment: @Hank, you can add anything you want, just try to avoid collisions with properties and methods used by the framework. ;)

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that I could do what I intend to do with the md material...so you answered my question, thx